# JSON to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a program that produce a JSON format. What I want to do is to store the json result into array in C#.

the json receive from API:

```
var strResponseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Result.Text = strResponseContent.ToString(); **<-- this is working fine**
```

here is the look of json:

```
{
    "query": "banana",
    "topScoringIntent": {
        "intent": "banana",
        "score": 0.9086001
    },
    "intents": [{
            "intent": "banana",
            "score": 0.9086001
        }, {
            "intent": "bananania",
            "score": 0.559515059
        }
    ]
}
```

and to store the json into array. here is the structure:

```
public class Intents
    {
        public List<Intent> intents { get; set; }
    }

    public class Intent
    {
        public string intent { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
    }
```

and finally, to convert, I use the deserialize object

```
Intents intents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Intent>(strResponseContent);
```

however, during the store into json, the error comes like **"can't implicitly convert type Intent to Intents"**

what Is my mistake? how to correct it?

Comment: You are passing `Intent` as type argument to `DeserializeObject` where you should pass `Intents`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two things first score is not a valid int... so, try changing int for Decimal.
And second try doing this:

```
Intents intents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Intents>(strResponseContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You defined the score as integer

```
 public int score { get; set; }
```

but score is not integer. changing it to double or decimal will fix it.

Comment: I recommend comparing your answer to the accepted answer to see where you went wrong :-)

Comment: John, I didn't go wrong. When I answered this question, Geraldo had mentioned the first issue. I didn't want to repeat whatever he answered. I had found another issue and I mentioned it. I feel that answer edited later by adding score issue.